# Checkbox control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have one problem controlling checkbox, i'm reading, and searching about the topic but i can't find anything that works for me, first i have 3 checkboxes on a asp.net mvc form

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbCodigo") %> <label class="inline" for="Codigo">Codigo</label>
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbNombreCliente") %> <label class="inline" for="NombreCliente">Nombre del cliente</label>
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbCiudad") %> <label class="inline" for="Ciudad">Ciudad</label>
```

i want to control using jquery, that the user, just can check one of the checkbox, i try to use hide(); if the user check one checkbox the others just hide, but the control of the events is so hard, that isn't the best way to do that i think.

thanks

Edit: answer to my own question

i know it´s just to rare hide the other options, i just want to "lock" the other options when i checked one of them, i solve it with this:

```
$('#cbCodigo').change(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#cbNombreCliente').prop("checked", false);
                    $('#cbCiudad').prop("checked", false);
                }
            });

$('#cbNombreCliente').change(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#cbCodigo').prop("checked", false);
                    $('#cbCiudad').prop("checked", false);
                }
            });

$('#cbCiudad').change(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#cbCodigo').prop("checked", false);
                    $('#cbNombreCliente').prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: provide the HTML markup generated by this code please

Comment: If you are limited to just one choice, why not use radio buttons instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $checkboxes = $('#cbCodigo, #cbNombreCliente, #cbCiudad');

$checkboxes.change(function(){
        $checkboxes.not(this).hide();
    });
```

Though I can't really understand why do you need such a weird requirement.
Don't you want letting the user revert his choice with other checkbox?

Comment: thanks man finally i found how to do what i want, alredy edit my question,i hope that is usefull for somebody else

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa. You should write the answer as an answer, not edit your question. don't forget to accept an answer.

Comment: alredy try it, but i need to wait 8 hours for answer my own question